# error on loading files using numpy python

Tags: python, numpy

i have many text files that contain integers present inside a directory `/home/gkl/file/*.rtd.2_file_*.txt_*`

i just want to load using numpy and i am getting error

```
import numpy as np
import glob
import os

files = [os.path.basename(x) for x in glob.glob("/home/gkl/file/*.rtd.2_file_*.txt_*")]
print(files)
inpdata=np.loadtxt(names)
print(inpdata)
```

i am getting error ValueError: could not convert string to float: `'mst.rtd.2_file_345.txt_1'`

after that i tried

```
import numpy as np
import glob
import os

files = [os.path.basename(x) for x in glob.glob("/home/gkl/file/*.rtd.2_file_*.txt_*")]
print(files)
inpdata=np.loadtxt(float(names))
print(inpdata)
```

still i get error

```
inpdata=np.loadtxt(float(names))
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'
```

i need experts help here

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have a list of file names, but [`np.loadtxt`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) expects a single file or filename. So you essentially have to call `loadtxt` in a for-loop:

```py
import numpy as np
import glob
import os

files = [os.path.basename(x) for x in glob.glob("/home/gkl/file/*.rtd.2_file_*.txt_*")]
print(files)
inpdata = [np.loadtxt(file) for file in files]
print(inpdata)
```

If this still does not work I'd need to see what is in the files to debug further.